# Highcharts Align HTML Right when Window Resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I have added custom text to a chart. The chart is fluid and adjusts it's size when the browser window is resized.

Is there any way that I can set the "Monitored Systems" and "Vulnerabilities" sections to be aligned right so that they will resize along with the rest of the chart?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fyatjhg9/1/)

```
function(chart) { // on complete

chart.renderer.html('<div align="center" style="color: #333333; font-size: 36px; font-weight: bold; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">96</div><div align="center" style="margin: -10px; padding: 0px;">Monitored Systems</div>', 350, 0)
    .css({
        color: '#999999',
        fontSize: '13px'

    })
    .add(); 



    chart.renderer.html('<div align="center" style="color: #333333; font-size: 36px; font-weight: bold; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">6</div><div align="center" style="margin: -10px; padding: 0px;"><i class="fa fa-warning" title="Warning"></i> Vulnerabilities</div>', 515, 0)
    .css({
        color: '#999999',
        fontSize: '13px'

    })
    .add(); 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the html elements [chart.events.redraw](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.redraw). You can calculate their new position based on `chart.plotLeft` and `chart.plotWidth`.

```
chart: {
renderTo: 'cont_monitor',
marginTop: 50,
backgroundColor: 'transparent',
events: {
  redraw: function() {
    var elements = this.HTMLElements,
        offsetWidth = 0,
        i = elements.length;

    while (--i > -1) {
      offsetWidth += elements[i].getBBox().width + 75;
   //  offsetWidth += 235;
      elements[i].attr({
        x: this.plotLeft + this.plotWidth - offsetWidth
      });
    }
  }
}
},
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/cdmv0cys/

Comment: This is working great for when the browser window is resized.  Is there any way to figure out the correct location on initial page load?  Currently, the data is loaded where I'm specifying the X,Y coordinates, but on resize,  the resize kicks in.

Comment: Nevermind, I added chart.plotWidth - specified offset to where i"m defining the X coordinate and it's working great now.. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what you should do in your initial callback.